# How can I adjust values in a timeseries to account for effects from other variable(s)? i.e. using a GAM

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, mixed-model, generalized-additive-model, adjustment

I have a dataset of monthly air pollution levels (i.e. PM2.5) as well as a corresponding dataset with monthly rainfall amount (i.e mm) spanning several years. These datasets have moderately strong, negative relationship (i.e. R-squared = 0.6). I show an example of the data below.[image: Example data]

I have read in several articles where people describe adjusting ozone levels based on meteorology effects using Generalized Additive Models (GAM) ([such as this article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1352231007004165))[image]

However, I don't really understand how this is done as the articles are not very descriptive. For example, which functions and parameters would be selected in R or python GAM implementations and why? Usually the examples I find only provide examples of smoothing.

Any thoughts or suggestions or tutorial links would be greatly appreciated. I am also open to other suggestions which use different methods aside from GAMs.

Comment: Check Gavin Simpson's blog post on ["Modelling seasonal data with GAMs"](http://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2014/05/09/modelling-seasonal-data-with-gam/); I think you will find it very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked me to work my special magic on your data using automatic software ... I introduced your 60 monthly values for two time series to AUTOBOX , my preferred tool of choice ( since I helped develop it). No hint whatsoever was provided to the system regarding a theoretical expectation of seasonal factors in BC .

Adjusting one series for 1 or more supportive series is basically the predicted value from a transfer function (regression + ). Predicted values need to be sometimes adjusted for exogenous (unspecified outside) effects whose form needs to be established after adJusting for memory (ARIMA). If you wish to post your data I will try to  help further.

EDITED AFTER RECEIPT OF DATA :

The idea is simple enough ... form a useful model between BC and Rainfall.  Following https://web.archive.org/web/20160216193539/https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/node/75/ while being concerned with possible anomalies and changes in model error variance http://docplayer.net/12080848-Outliers-level-shifts-and-variance-changes-in-time-series.html we use the following flow diagram as a paradigm http://autobox.com/cms/images/dllupdate/TFFLOW.png for the steps in the analysis.

The transfer function equation suggests non-constant error variance and a few anomalies pulses and 1 level shift and three very definite deterministic/fixed seasonal effects.  [image] i.e. 3 seasonal pulses (march/june/november) . The original plot of Y (BC) is here [image] and X (RAINFALL) is here [image] . Using Tsay's method if testing for constant error process variability ( always a good idea ! ) we obtained [image] time period 48 as a break point given the effect of X and the three seasonal dummies.

A plot of the residuals form the model ( another good idea ! ) suggest sufficiency [image] as does the ACF of the errors [image] . The ACTUAL and the CLEANSED DATA is shown  here  [image] . At the end of the day the FITTED VALUES from the model shown here with the ACTUAL [image] and partially here in tabular form [image] reflect BC adjusted for RAINFALL and the identified repetitive (seasonal pulse; level shift ) and one-time only deterministic components (pulses).

In effect we have identified the need to adjust BC for Rain while also adjusting for seasonality and anomalous values & increased variability over time starting at period 48. The automatic identification  of the three seasonal dummies supports your hypothesis thus all is good ... data analysis can be used to support prior degrees of belief ! These seasonal factors represent ADDITIONAL IMPACT above and beyond the normal response of BC to RAINFALL.

Comment: Thanks for specifying these details and offering to help further, I greatly appreciate it. I'm posting the CSV on my github [here](https://github.com/toferkey/scratchdata/blob/master/BC_RainfallData_StackExchange.csv). If you get a chance to offer any focused help I would greatly appreciate it. In the mean time, I'm going to be reviewing the long blog post posted by user11852. Thanks!

Comment: Am I correct that you wish to model air polution(bc) it relates to rainfall while taking into account any lag structures  and anomalies while testing and incorporating for non-constant error process suggesting a possible non-linear relationship.

Comment: It may be simpler than that. I specifically want to look at the timeseries air pollution data to tease out any increase during the biomass burning months of March, June, and october (releasing a lot of BC). However, the rainfall is generally reducing the BC amount. It makes it difficult to compare BC across months. So taking into account the lag structure (i.e. in months) may not be necessary, but the non-constant error processes would likely be beneficial.

Comment: lag structures reflect the possicble impact of previous values for either BC the Y variable OR rainfall the X variable.. Nothing to do with the counting numbers ,1,2,3,...60

Comment: Great to see the step-by-step with graphs! So in essence it seems that the fitted values are just the actual + residual? Thank you!

Comment: Yes . I learned from your post that GAMS can be a useful tool to solve optimization problems by using the language of mathematics. What you want to do is to IDENTIFY the equation and then possibly use GAMS ...that is called the scientific method often supported by a pre-specified theory or suggested model. I don't initially see GAMS application to your problem BUT I would like to be educated in that regard as truth and understanding regarding analytics is an evolutionary process.

Comment: or maybe GAM is not the same as GAMS ...I am confused ...apparently https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_additive_model  is useful for polynomials and splines  which is far afield from where you are. It might be a solution looking for a problem BUT not your problem.